# What data is saved in Hyperledger Fabric for the situation as explained below

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

Sarah sell USD50/lb to A and USD80/lb to B Now B should not be able to see Sarah and A's transaction... Correct me if I am wrong.

What data is saved in Sarah's blockchain, A's blockchain and B's Blockchain??

///////////

Transaction1 : Sarah to A-- USD50

Transaction2 : Sarah to B-- USD80

/////////

Sarah:

```
Transaction hash 1 and 2

Details of transaction (USD50 for A and USD80 for B)
```

A:

```
Transaction Hash 1 and 2

Details of transaction(USD50 for sarah,no information of transaction2 )
```

B:

```
Transaction hash 1 and 2

Details of transaction(USD80 for sarah, no info of Transaction1 )
```

Correct if I am wrong? Does this way things work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main options. Utilize channels so that separate ledgers are created, or embed access security in the Smart Contract so only the parties to a transaction can view it.